# Spring Data JPA cannot recognize the class

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, backend

I have completely given up hope of solving this problem myself and hopefully I can get some help here.

For some reason, my class is not recognized as an entity, and I'm getting the following error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cardRepository' defined in ua.com.alevel.persistence.repository.card.CardRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on HibernateConfig: Not a managed type: class ua.com.alevel.persistence.entity.Card
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1770) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:598) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:254) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1417) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1337) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:888) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:791) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    ... 38 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class ua.com.alevel.persistence.entity.Card
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.model.domain.internal.JpaMetamodelImpl.managedType(JpaMetamodelImpl.java:192) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.6.Final.jar:6.2.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.model.domain.internal.MappingMetamodelImpl.managedType(MappingMetamodelImpl.java:467) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.6.Final.jar:6.2.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.model.domain.internal.MappingMetamodelImpl.managedType(MappingMetamodelImpl.java:97) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.6.Final.jar:6.2.6.Final]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.<init>(JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.java:80) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaEntityInformationSupport.getEntityInformation(JpaEntityInformationSupport.java:69) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getEntityInformation(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:246) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:211) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:194) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:81) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:317) ~[spring-data-commons-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$5(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:279) ~[spring-data-commons-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:245) ~[spring-data-commons-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:114) ~[spring-data-commons-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:285) ~[spring-data-commons-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:132) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1817) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1766) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
```

If I move this class to my other project, with the same configuration, everything works fine, but here it refuses....

My BaseEntity abstract class (card and User inherit from it):

```
package ua.com.alevel.persistence.entity;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Date;

@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class BaseEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date created;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date updated;

    private boolean visible;

    public BaseEntity() {
        this.created = new Date();
        this.updated = new Date();
        this.visible = true;
    }

    @PreUpdate
    public void onPreUpdate() {
        this.updated = new Date();
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Date getCreated() {
        return created;
    }

    public void setCreated(Date created) {
        this.created = created;
    }

    public Date getUpdated() {
        return updated;
    }

    public void setUpdated(Date updated) {
        this.updated = updated;
    }

    public boolean getVisible() {
        return visible;
    }

    public void setVisible(boolean visible) {
        this.visible = visible;
    }
}
```

And here's the class responsible for this error:

```
package ua.com.alevel.persistence.entity;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

@Entity
@Table(name = "cards")
public class Card extends BaseEntity {
    @Column(name = "card_number")
    private String number;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date validUntil;

    @Column(name = "card_cvv")
    private String cvv;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "card_owner_id", nullable = false)
    private User owner;

    @Column(name = "card_balance")
    private BigDecimal balance;

    public Card() {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.add(Calendar.YEAR, 4);
        validUntil = calendar.getTime();

        balance = BigDecimal.valueOf(0);
    }

    public Card(String number, Date validUntil, String cvv, BigDecimal balance) {
        this.number = number;
        this.validUntil = validUntil;
        this.cvv = cvv;
        this.balance = balance;
    }

    public String getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public void setNumber(String number) {
        this.number = number;
    }

    public Date getValidUntil() {
        return validUntil;
    }

    public void setValidUntil(Date validUntil) {
        this.validUntil = validUntil;
    }

    public String getCvv() {
        return cvv;
    }

    public void setCvv(String cvv) {
        this.cvv = cvv;
    }

    public User getOwner() {
        return owner;
    }

    public void setOwner(User owner) {
        this.owner = owner;
    }

    public BigDecimal getBalance() {
        return balance;
    }

    public void setBalance(BigDecimal balance) {
        this.balance = balance;
    }
}
```

I will also attach a Hibernate configuration class here:

```
package ua.com.alevel.config;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

import javax.sql.DataSource;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Properties;

@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories("ua.com.alevel.persistence.repository")
public class HibernateConfig {

    @Value("${spring.datasource.url}")
    private String jdbcUrl;

    @Value("${spring.datasource.username}")
    private String username;

    @Value("${spring.datasource.password}")
    private String password;

    @Value("${spring.datasource.driver-class-name}")
    private String driver;

    @Value("${spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect}")
    private String dialect;

    @Value("${spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto}")
    private String hbm2ddl;

    @Value("${spring.jpa.show-sql}")
    private Boolean showSql;

    @Value("${spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.max_size}")
    private String maxSize;

    @Value("${spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.min_size}")
    private String minSize;

    @Value("${spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.batch_size}")
    private String batchSize;

    @Value("${spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size}")
    private String fetchSize;

    @Value("${spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans}")
    private String lazyLoad;

    private static final String HIBERNATE_DIALECT = "hibernate.dialect";
    private static final String HIBERNATE_HBM2DDL_AUTO = "hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto";
    private static final String HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL = "hibernate.show_sql";
    private static final String HIBERNATE_ENABLE_LAZY_LOAD_NO_TRANS = "hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans";
    private static final String MAX_SIZE = "hibernate.c3p0.max_size";
    private static final String MIN_SIZE = "hibernate.c3p0.min_size";
    private static final String BATCH_SIZE = "hibernate.jdbc.batch_size";
    private static final String FETCH_SIZE = "hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size";
    private static final String ENTITY_MANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN = "ua.com.alevel.persistence.entity";

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(driver);
        dataSource.setUrl(jdbcUrl);
        dataSource.setUsername(username);
        dataSource.setPassword(password);
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean(name = "entityManagerFactory")
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactoryBean() {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactoryBean = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
        sessionFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan(ENTITY_MANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN);
        sessionFactoryBean.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
        try {
            sessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return sessionFactoryBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        HibernateTransactionManager manager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        manager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactoryBean().getObject());
        return manager;
    }

    private Properties hibernateProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put(HIBERNATE_DIALECT, dialect);
        properties.put(HIBERNATE_HBM2DDL_AUTO, hbm2ddl);
        properties.put(HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL, showSql);
        properties.put(HIBERNATE_ENABLE_LAZY_LOAD_NO_TRANS, lazyLoad);
        properties.put(MAX_SIZE, maxSize);
        properties.put(MIN_SIZE, minSize);
        properties.put(BATCH_SIZE, batchSize);
        properties.put(FETCH_SIZE, fetchSize);
        return properties;
    }
}
```

I'll also attach the main class:

```
package ua.com.alevel;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration;

@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {
        DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class,
        DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration.class,
        HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class})
public class FinancesMicroservicesApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(FinancesMicroservicesApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

I don't know how to fix it anymore:(

I'll add the architecture of the project as well:
[image]

Comment: I have a class User, where everything is done as in the class Card (of course with other fields).
User works, but Card does not.

Answer (score 1):

You should try to add @EntityScan(basePackages = {"ua.com.alevel.persistence.entity"})

Is your concrete entity in the same module/project than your config ?

Comment: Yes, I'm the one with 2 modules that don't connect anything but a single database(1 module is responsible for user authentication and everything related to it, and the 2nd module is responsible for creating and working with maps). 
Hibernate setup and the whole project configuration is the same, only I run them on different ports.

Tried adding @EntityScan(basePackages = {"ua.com.alevel.persistence.entity"}), but nothing changed

I have a different configuration for each of the modules(it's the same, but it's in each of them)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix it. Apparently I had outdated dependencies in pom.xml and something was conflicting somewhere. I updated the file and everything worked!